# Creating a debian package, what do I specify in debian/rules to run a ruby script?

Tags: debian, puppet, dpkg

I am building a package for Puppet facter. The installation of puppet facter is as follows:

1. make sure ruby is installed on the OS
2. run `ruby install.rb`

So I'd like to make a Debian package out of it. What should the contents of my debian/rules file be? The following does not work (creates a .deb that is empty):

```
#!/usr/bin/gmake -f
%:
    dh $@

override_dh_install:
    ruby install.rb
```

Comment: you sure the shebang is correct? It should be `#!`, no just `#`.

Comment: Fixed. It's strange, facter gets installed during the dpkg-buildpackage run, but the resulting .deb file is essentially empty.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that specifying destination directory to be inside my playground solved the issue. My rules file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gmake -f

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_installdeb:
        echo '+++ +++ installing facter.'
        ruby install.rb --destdir=/root/projects/package-facter/facter-2.0.0rc4/debian/facter

override_dh_auto_test:
        a='a' # do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `debian/rules` file, you have to give the install location to `install.rb`:

```
ruby install.rb --destdir=$(CURDIR)/debian/facter
```

Don't hardcode the fullpath path to your project directory in `debian/rules`.  That is very brittle.